# bit values from 0 to 255 for valid IP address

Tags: python

```
b = str(input())
k = b.split('.') 
l = len(k)
print(l)
for  i  in  range(0, l):
    if int(k[i]) < 256 and int(k[i]) >= 0 :
           print('YES')
    else:
           print('NO')
```

Why is YES is not printed one time when all element of k string is check i? What if all element satisfy the condition print'YES'? On the Internet, each computer is assigned a four-byte code which is usually written in the form of four numbers, each of which can take values from 0 to 255, separated by dots. Here are examples of correct IP addresses:

```
127.0.0.0
192.168.0.1
255.0.255.255
```

Write a program that determines if a given string is a valid IP address

Comment: Please format your code to be human readable

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include the actual output and the expected output.

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking us to write code for you?

Comment: Why is "YES" not printed once? Because it's in a `for` loop that checks if every part of the IP is between 0 and 255.

Comment: "Why is YES is not printed one time when all element of k string is check i?" Why do you think this should happen? Did you try to trace through the logic of the code, one step at a time? "What if all element satisfy the condition print'YES'?" I don't understand what this is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you for some reason can't use imports, i.e. it is a homework to do it without, following is working version of your code:

```
b = str(input())
k = b.split('.')

if (len(k)!=4):
  print("input length is incorrect")
else:
  error = False
  for  num  in  k:
      if int(num)<0 or int(num)>255:
        print('Error in your IP addr')
        error = True
        break
  if not error:
    print("Your IP addr is valid")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have built in support in python to test this with the [ipaddress module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html)

```
ipaddress.ip_address('192.168.0.1')
```

Will throw an Value error if not valid

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want "YES" or "NO" to be printed only once.
So here is a simple to understand program that does so:

```
b = str(input())
k = b.split('.') 
l = len(k)

ip = True

if l != 4:
    ip = False
else:
    for  i  in  range(l):
        if int(k[i])< 255 and int(k[i]) >= 0:
            continue
        else:
            ip = False
            break

if ip:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

But if it's not a homework and you can use modules, go for StefanE's answer.

Comment: yes i did not think that way thanks bro @Chris Rahmé

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept my or any other answer that helped you so that the question gets marked as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are printing `Yes` or `No` in each iteration. You can create a variable to act as a flag, if `f_invalid` is `False` at the end of the loop then you can print `Yes`, otherwise you print `No`.

```
b = str(input())
k = b.split('.') 
l = len(k)
print(l)

f_invalid = False

for  i  in  range(0, l):
    if not(int(k[i]) < 256 and int(k[i]) >= 0) :
           f_invalid = True

print("Yes") if not f_invalid else print("No")
```